# what is the alternative to localformat

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, we are using jquery datepicker in multiple pages of the project, i used toLocaleFormat to convert a date to a string, toLocaleFormat worked fine till mozilla 57 versions, suddenly when i updated to Mozilla 58 + versions datepicker stopped working, because of toLocaleFormat was deprecated. Is there any other alternative that serves my scenario .

**> Required Format : 16-May-2018**

Code used in my project:

```
var today=new
 Date().toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
    var _todayPlus30Days=new Date();
    _todayPlus30Days.setDate(_todayPlus30Days.getDate() + 29); 
        _todayPlus30Days=_todayPlus30Days.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
        $('#creditLetterDateId').DatePicker({ 
        format:
            'd-M-Y',default_position :'below',start_date:today, onSelect:
             function(d,i){if(d !== i.lastVal){$(this).change();}}      
        }).val(today);
        $("#creditLetterDateId").change(function(){
            /*var date2 = $('#creditLetterDateId').datepicker('getDate');           
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+30); 
            $("#cardvalidityDateId").datepicker({ 
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
             }).datepicker("setDate", new Date(date2));*/   
        
             var _dateStr=$(this).val().replace(/-/g,' ');
             var _date = new Date(_dateStr);            
            _date.setDate(_date.getDate() + 29);
            _date=_date.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
            $('#cardvalidityDateId').DatePicker({
                format: 'd-M-Y',default_position :'below',start_date:_date, 
                onSelect: function(d,i){if(d !== i.lastVal)
                 {$(this).change();}}           
             }).val(_date);
         });
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_toLocaleFormat) for Mozilla's documentation on the deprecated syntax and what they recommend using, like, `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString`.